# simple join of three tables in LINQ

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

i dont understand linq properly. i dont know why.

i have three tables.

1)TillTable

```
  tillId,    tillName
      1             w1
      2             w2
      3             w3
      4             w4
```

2)TillDepartment

```
   tillDeptId,  tillId,  deptId,  isPart
        1        1          5         1
        2        1          7         0
        3        1          8         0
        4        1          9         0
        5        2          5         0
         6       2           7         0
         7       2           8         0
         8       2           9         0
         9       3           5          0
        10      3           7          1
        11       3          8          0
         12      3           9         0         
        13       4           5         0 
        14       4           7         0
        15        4          9         0      so on....
```

3) departmentTable

```
   deptId,         deptName
       5               Science 
       7               Commerce 
       8               history
       9               English        so on....
```

now using linq or lambda exp i want to display following result,

```
    tillId,   tillName,     deptName
      1          w1              science 
      2          w2              no dept
      3          w3              commerce
      4          w4              no dept     so on...
```

i hope for linq master its damn easy task....

help me to get it resolved....

if isPart column is 1 then in result set deptName should be displayed else 'no dept' ....
associative table has multiple entries for tillId..... 
its requirement so strictly follow this scenario only.....

i hope its clr ......

Comment: Well what have you tried so far? If someone just gives you the answer, you won't learn nearly as much as if you explain what you've tried and what happens, and we can guide you from there to the right approach.

Comment: i have tried so many stuffs. but i m only getting result set having 'no null' value... i dont know abt linq join syntax..  i dobt have laptop right now with me else would have shown you what i have done so far.  i m writing this all with mobile so not able to write all stuffs.  sorry for that.....

Comment: Then I suggest you delete this question until you're in a position to do a good job of it. (I also suggest you write in full words, with proper capitalization and punctuation. It's *much* easier to read questions written that way.)

Comment: i have limitations right now.  no one wants write query or ask query using mobile in stack overflow as it becomes very hard to go in right direction.... still I have tried to make it very clear...

Comment: So don't... wait until you're at a laptop before you ask a question. Being on a mobile device isn't a good excuse for asking a bad question with no sign of what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
var result = (from tt in db.tillTables
              join td in db.tillDepts
              on tt.tillId equals td.tillId
              join dt in db.departmentTable
              on td.deptid equals dt.deptId
              select new
                   {
                       tillId = tt.tillId,
                       tillName = tt.tillName,
                       deptName = td.isPart == 1 ? dt.deptName : null
                   }).GroupBy(x => x.tillId)
                     .Select(x =>
                             {
                              var orderedDeptRecord = x.OrderByDescending(z => z.deptName).FirstOrDefault();
                              return new
                              {
                                  tillId = x.Key,
                                  tillName = orderedDeptRecord.tillName,
                                  deptName = orderedDeptRecord.deptName
                              };
                    });
```

Comment: @micronyks - Its working for me. What do you mean by "the way i want"? can you explain your "way"?

Comment: pls check now. in ur case it returns so many rows. but actually i want to have result set as shown above..... its sohuld map dept name if isPart is 1.....  i hope u understand what i want.....

Comment: @micronyks - Your data structure is very confusing, what is `tillDeptId` used for? Is that a primary key on that table?

Comment: yes tillDeptId is PK.  i know its complex.  but i have to find an ans.  its a big mistake by else developer....

Comment: do u have any solution?

Comment: @micronyks - Yup, please check have updated the answer, its working for me.

Comment: i dont think so it will work.  i think it will return again multiple rows.  i want to get no of rows equal to tillTable rows with associated departmentName.....  still i will check n let u know.....

Comment: @micronyks - How come you can say it won't work without testing? I have spent some time brother on it, at least appreciate that, its working as expected, i.e. the way you have posted, if you want i can share the screenshot.

Comment: yup man.  really appreciate ur work n efforts behind it.  if it works,  ur help would be more appreciated.  thanks by d way....

Comment: it shows expression tree error or something with me...... it gives error at   .select(x)  here it shows tree error something....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67144/discussion-between-rahul-singh-and-micronyks).

Comment: @micronyks - Can you post the full exception details?

Comment: sure. i ll let u know my prbms by writing further....  n thanks for ur interest....  seriously man i need ur help on this.......

Answer (score 0):

Outer join to single record,then, the foreign key to the deptName is the select clause with ternary operator (gets translated to "case")

```
from t in TillTable
join tds in TillDepartment on new { t.tillId,isPart=1}
                       equals new { td.tillId, isPart } into tdOuter
from td in tdOuter.DefaultIfEmpty().Take(1)
select new { t.tillId, t.tillName, 
        deptName=((td==null)? "no dept" :
            (from dt in departmentTable 
            where dt.deptId == td.deptId
            select deptName ) ) }
```